# How to export a PDF with figures on multiple pages?

Tags: matlab, pdf, export

I am trying to export a larger number of Matlab figures that are generated in for loop to a single PDF file. Right now the best thing I could come up with is to all print them to a PostScrip file using the `-append` option like this:

```
print('Temp_Plots','-dpsc','-append')
```

After that I could convert the PS file to a PDF file. This workflow was okay until I started to use plots with 2 y axis. Unfortunately it seems like Matlab's PS export cannot properly handle this situation and does not color the lines appropriately.

As there is no `-append` option for the direct PDF export what other methods do I have to append all my plots to a single file without losing the assigned colors or other hickups?

Comment: Is there a reason the [`publish`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html) command isn't suitable?

Comment: I actually never used `publish` before. It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend trying out the [`publish`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html) command and push that to its limits first.

Following the documentation:

```
options = struct('format','pdf','outputDir','C:\myPublishedOutput');`
publish('myCode.m',options);
```

Take a look at [**Publishing Markup**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html) to see how to get the look you want.

This [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+publish+to+pdf) brings up some possibly related posts, but none that I saw that directly match your issue.

References:
1. [Publishing Markup](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html) (Mathworks)
2. [Output Preferences for Publishing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/specifying-output-preferences-for-publishing.html) (Mathworks)
3. [Publishing M-Files in MATLAB](http://math.loyola.edu/~loberbro/matlab/Publishing.pdf)
4. [Publish Your Work](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs310-1/modules/Numeric%20Computation/Matlab%20Reference/Publish%20Your%20Work/TopicDiscussion.html) in Matlab